# how to create table with only the information i want in R

Tags: r, string

I could sort out the list of proteins into single proteins without _P01,_P02...etc, However I couldn't manage to create the file that contains only the proteins that are significant with + and ! with there Log2 values

```
| Fasta headers       | Mass |Log2  |Significance|
| --------            | ---- |
| AB_P01;DE_P02;SG_P03| 3030 | 1.12 | +          |
| CD_P01;SH_P02;SR_P03| 1242 | 2.15 | !          |
| EF_P01;EJ_P02;AG_P03| 3030 | 0.12 | 
| GG_P01;HG_P02;QG_P03| 1242 | -2.15| !          |

I would like to have this in the end
| Fasta headers |Log2  |Significance|
| AB            | 1.12 | +          |
| DE            | 1.12 | +          |
| SG            | 1.12 | +          |
| CD            | 2.15 | !          |
| SH            | 2.15 | !          |
| SR            | 2.15 | !          |
| GG            | -2.15| !          |
| HG            | -2.15| !          |
| QG            | -2.15| !          |

library(readxl)
totalproteome <- read_excel("C:/Users/cd.xlsx", sheet = 4,range = ("A2:A5000"),skip = 1)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
totalproteome %>% 
  separate_rows(`Fasta headers`, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate(`Fasta headers` = trimws(`Fasta headers`, whitespace = "_.*")) %>%
  distinct -> a

    library(writexl)
    write_xlsx(a,"BOOK.xlsx")'
```

This is what I have to remove the deplicates from the first fasta headers, but I didn't manage to generate files containing only Fasta headers,Log2, and significance. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(`Fasta headers`, sep = ";") %>% # separate the Fasta headers out into new rows
    mutate(`Fasta headers` = str_remove(`Fasta headers`, "_P\\d+")) %>% # remove stuff from the end of Fasta headers
    select(-Mass) %>%
    filter(Significance != "") %>% # remove empty Significance rows
    distinct() # distinct doesn't do anything with the data you shared, but maybe it would if your actual dataset is larger

  `Fasta headers`  Log2 Significance
  <chr>           <dbl> <chr>       
1 AB               1.12 +           
2 DE               1.12 +           
3 SG               1.12 +           
4 CD               2.15 !           
5 SH               2.15 !           
6 SR               2.15 !           
7 GG              -2.15 !           
8 HG              -2.15 !           
9 QG              -2.15 !
```